# Java TCP - Sending a file using DataOutputStream

Tags: java, tcp

Hi and thanks in advance.

So currently, I am trying to have my TCP program read a file from a directory (this is server side), and then send that file over to the socket that requested it (the client).

Here is my code:

Server side:

```
File FileList = new File(".....filepath....");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(FileList);

//idToFile just searching for the name of the file the client asked for
String TheName = idToFile(Integer.toString(result));

//Opens the chosen file such as an image to be used     
File myImageFile = new File("....filepath...." + TheName);

//sendResponse is a function with a writeUTF (but only works for strings)
sendResponse("#OK");
sendResponse(TheName);
sendResponse(Long.toString(myImageFile.length()));

//This line causes the error and says that it expected a string and not a file          
output.writeUTF(myImageFile);


private void sendResponse(String response)
    {
        try 
        {
            output.writeUTF(response);
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Client side:

```
ClientHandler client = new ClientHandler();


//getResponse just catches the written strings, but it can't work with a file either
String TheMessage = client.getResponse();
String Name = client.getResponse();
long FileSize = Long.parseLong(client.getResponse());
```

Here is the code for ClientHandler:

```
public class ClientHandler 
{
    private static int port = 2016;

    private DataInputStream input;
    private DataOutputStream output;

    private Socket cSocket; 


    public ClientHandler()
    {
        cSocket = null;

        try
        {
            cSocket = new Socket("localhost", port); //connecting to the server 
            System.out.println("Client is connected on port " + port);

            output = new DataOutputStream(cSocket.getOutputStream());
            input = new DataInputStream(cSocket.getInputStream());
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) //checking if the message is sent
    {
        try
        {
            output.writeUTF(message);
            output.flush();
            System.out.println("Message sent to the server");
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getResponse()
    {
        String msg = "";
        try
        {
              msg = input.readUTF();
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        return msg;
    }

}
```

So how can I use a DataOutputStream to send any kind of file from my server to my client, and how can my client catch that file using DataInputStream and save it to disk?

Thank you.

Comment: what is `output`? Can you share a snippet of `sendResponse` ?

Comment: What is all this? What are you using? `sendResponse` `output` `client` ???

Comment: I will add them all now

Comment: Just added the other stuff. I hope its enough.

Comment: You could consider using a well-established protocol for this, like HTTP.

Comment: My code is study material for a test. I have to use data streams.

Comment: You should learn more about [IO Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html), basic file IO and [networking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/index.html). `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` are not meant to be used to transfer files.

Comment: What kind of streams or such would I need to transfer files? e.g. an image

Comment: @Duckman You can use BufferedOutputStream and BufferedInputStream

Answer (score 1):

Create a new instance of *DataOutputStream* and *DataInputStream* as shown below.

```
DataOutputStream socketOut = new DataOutputStream(socketObject.getOutputStream());
DataInputStream  socketIn  = new DataInputStream(socketObject.getInputStream());
```

For sample code, checkout the sample class shown [in this lecture notes.](http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/Teaching/CSAS2214/Virtual/Lectures/lecture18.html)

For quick reference, here are the snippets from the sample class

```
DataInputStream streamIn = new 
              DataInputStream(new 
              BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream()));
String incomingDataLine = streamIn.readLine();
...
...
DataOutputStream socketOut = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
socketOut.writeBytes(line + '\n');
```

========= Edit 1: After reading your comments

Anything over the network is 1s and 0s i.e. bytes. 
Let's say you want to transfer an image from one server to another then the recommended way is for the server to read the file contents as bytes`java.nio.Files.readAllBytes()` and write this to the socket.

On the client side, read all the bytes from socket (using BufferedReader in practical projects) and write them to disk. You have to make sure both server and client are using the same encoding.

Use BufferedInputStream and BufferedOutputStream instead of DataXXXStream.

This will work for any file type - mp3, mp4, jpeg, png, acc, txt, java. To have it usable in client system, make sure to create a file with the correct extension.

Comment: Its not that I want to send a string. I want to be able to send a file such as a text files,  image files, or video files. Basically I need to be able to send those kinds of files (or technically any other) over my stream.

Comment: @Duckman Anything over the network is 1s and 0s i.e. bytes. If you'd like to send file content, then serialize the java.nio.File object (not recommended) or get it's content as bytes using java.nio.Files.readAllBytes().

Answer (score 0):

Here as an example a simple server, which sends a binary file to each client without further interaction.

The socket provides the output stream to write bytes to the client. We have a file "picin.jpg" we want to send, so we need to write every byte of this file to the socket's output stream. In order to do that, we use a `FileInputStream` wrapped in a `BufferedInputStream`.

```
package networking;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket();
      ss.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 4711));
      for(;;) {
        Socket sock = ss.accept();
        System.out.println("Connected to " + sock.getInetAddress());
        try (
          InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("picin.jpg"));
          OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();
        ) 
        {
          int bytesSent = Util.copy(in, out);
          System.out.println(String.format("%d bytes sent.", bytesSent));
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

I extracted the copy method to a util class, because we need the exact same in the client. We use a small byte array as a buffer and copy one chunk after another from one stream to the other.

```
package networking;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class Util {
  public static int copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    int totalBytes = 0;
    while((bytesRead = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
      totalBytes += bytesRead;
      out.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    return totalBytes;
  }

}
```

The client opens a connection to the server and write the received bytes to a file. The socket provides the input stream with the bytes coming from the server. We use a `FileOutputStream` wrapped in a `BufferedOutputStream` to write to the file. We use the same `Util.copy()` method to actually copy the bytes from one stream to the other.

```
package networking;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Socket sock = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 4711);
      try(
        InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("picout.jpg"))
      )
      {
        System.out.println("Connected to " + sock.getRemoteSocketAddress());
        int bytesCopied = Util.copy(in, out);
        System.out.println(String.format("%d bytes received", bytesCopied));
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Note: The streams are closed automatically by the try-with-ressources statement. The sockets are closed while the corresponding streams are closed.

Java 8 includes some convenience methods to copy bytes from a file to an output stream or from an input stream to a file. See [`java.nio.file.Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved a big chunk of what I need to do. So now it successfully saves an image file on the client side (but is does seem to chop off the last few bytes of the image), but it still shows an exception. Here it is:  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: len == -1 off == 0 buffer length == 4096. Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Also you mention that the stream are automatically closed, but I need them to stay open for one more action (the client using my logout button). Any idea how I can keep the streams open?

Comment: You should see this as a starting point. Do more on your own. If there is an exception read the exception class' docs. Read the docs for the specific function which throws the execption. Sometimes there is a hint when such exception is thrown. Learn how to use a debugger. Experiment with your code. Try to understand what each line of your code does. And if you want to keep a stream open, then don't close it before your work is done.